# Как сортировать список в словаре python?

Tags: python-3.5

Как сортировать один из списков  в словаре с помощью `sort()`? Это вообще   возможно?!

Comment: Добавь в вопрос твой список

Comment: inventory = ['backpack'].sort () вот этот метод подойдёт  !@kff                 я просто не умею редактировать свои сообщения ,я сдесь в первые ,а ответ мой на свой вопрос я нашел!